# How to self-reference resource output arn in the resource itself?

Tags: terraform

I know it is probably odd ask, but I need to create this resource `https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/dms_replication_task` and define its argument `task_mapping` using its arn. I know it is chicken and egg problem but I hope there is a way. For some stupid reason, AWS DMS service partition data using task arn and I need to use it in my mappings to work properly. But I only know ARN once it is created.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the API documentation you should be able to build the ARN:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/APIReference/API_CreateReplicationTask.html#DMS-CreateReplicationTask-request-ResourceIdentifier

sample arn:
`arn:aws:dms:eu-west-1:012345678901:rep:Example-App-ARN1`

breaking it down:
`arn:aws:dms:{region}:{account_id}:rep:{resource_id}`

---

Interestingly in the AWS console, we have an option to override the ARN with a friendly name
...but that is not available on this resourse

> Descriptive Amazon Resource Name (ARN) - optional
> A friendly name to override the default DMS ARN. You cannot modify it after creation.

[image]

---

Even on the AWS CLI that friendly ARN is not available:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dms/create-replication-task.html

Comment: thanks for responding. unfortunately, I need that resource_id part that is unknown when terraform runs. Friendly ARN would be awesome, actually lots of aws resources support it but not this one :(

Comment: @mishkin Ye, I thought that's what I was saying in my answer ...  currently not possible, the API supports it but the Terraform provider and CLI don't ... if you want to give it a shot this is the code for that resource in the provider:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/e06ee9e56dbdb75ca59c21fad0f2d8b24339f55e/aws/resource_aws_dms_replication_task.go#L19

Comment: Looking at the `terraform-provider-aws` repo on github (2,709 Open Issues) and (615 Pull Request) unlikely this will get fix any time soon, unless you know someone on that team